# pyTelegramBotAPI привязка фотографии к user_id

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, telebot

Доброго времени суток :)
Пытаюсь написать бота знакомств, где сначала идет регистрация юзера - создание анкеты.
Один из шагов включается в себя отправку юзером фотографии для анкеты и сохранение её в указанную папку сервера

```
def process_photo_step(message):
    try:
        if message.content_type == 'photo':
            chat_id = message.from_user.id
            user = user_dict[chat_id]
            user.photo_id = message.photo[-1].file_id

            file_photo = bot.get_file(user.photo_id)
            filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_photo.file_path)

            downloaded_file_photo = bot.download_file(file_photo.file_path)
            src = 'C:/python/Datingbot/dating/photos/' + user.photo_id + file_extension
            with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file_photo)

            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Расскажи о себе")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_about_step)
        else:
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Это не фотография, пришлите пожалуйста фото.')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_photo_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'уууупс')
```

По окончанию регистрации его введенные данные сохраняются в БД в таком виде:
[image: инфо бд]

А фотография, которую он отправил боту сохранилась в соответствующую папку
Дальше есть кнопка  **->** **начать поиск **-> *Девушку/Парня* 
На примере выбора "девушку" идет запрос в БД на рандомную анкету девушки

```
def procces_find_choice(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        if message.text == 'Девушку':
            mycursor.execute("SELECT name, city, age, about FROM users WHERE sex = 'Девушка' ")
            finds = mycursor.fetchall()
            name, city, age, about = random.choice(finds)
            profile = f'{name},\n {city}, {age}\n{about}'
            bot.send_photo(chat_id, user.photo_id, caption=profile)
```

в данном случае если пишу `user.photo_id`, то отправляются рандомная анкета из БД( так и должно), а вот фотография берется именно моя - оно в принципе и логично (сам регистрируюсь и провожу тест)
Не могу понять как именно можно реализовать привязку фотографии к определенной анкете...
 Недавно начал программирование изучать, поэтому буду рад любым советам и предложениям

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал написать свой класс, что-то типа:

```
class my_prof:
    id = 0
    chat_id = 123456789
    name = 'Вася'
    city = 'Москва'
    age = 20
    sex = 'парень'
    about = 'информация'
    photo = 'https://mysite.com/photo.jpg' # <-- ссылка на загруженное фото
```

Саму базу организовать как список:

```
profile = list()
```

И уже с ним работать по индексам (id):

```
# просто данные для примера
tmp_prof = my_prof()
tmp_prof.id = 158
tmp_prof.chat_id = 159753648264
tmp_prof.name = 'Петрович'
tmp_prof.city = 'д.Пукино'
tmp_prof.age = 105
tmp_prof.sex = 'дедуля'
tmp_prof.about = 'есть порох в пороховницах'
tmp_prof.photo = 'https://mysite.com/grandpa.jpg' # <-- ссылка на загруженное фото

profile.append(tmp_prof) # <-- добавляет анкету в конец списка

# допустим что мы добавляли анкету с номером 7, получим из нее адрес фото
print(profile[7].photo)
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Попробую по Вашему совету сделать) А на основе моего кода можно как-нибудь изощриться чтоб привязать загруженное фото юзером к его chat_id(телеграма) ?

Comment: может быть возможно сделать так:
создать вторую таблицу name "photo", где будет сохранятся путь до фото(которое юзер отправил). этому фото присваивается также chat_id, соответствующее этому юзеру ? Что-то типа такого

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень разобрался в вашем коде. У вас есть класс user со свойствами/аттрибутами типа photo_id. Предполагаю что в нем можно записать значение chat_id или прописать свой класс наследующий свойства user и добавить ему поле chat_id.

Или создать словарь, в котором будут записываться адреса фотографий, а ключами к ним будут как раз значения chat_id.

А еще лучше было бы хранить адреса фото в базе данных, тогда с доступом к ним по chat_id не было бы проблем. Только не вторую таблицу делать, а просто добавить столбец в имеющейся.